# ResXManger doesn't detect any code references for resources

Tags: visual-studio, localization, blazor, resx

The Visual-Studio extension ResXManager has a feature which is supposed to detect code references of resources.
However it shows zero code references for every resource.

I've tried to adjust the regular expressions in the configuration section, nothing worked.

Here is the default config:
[ResXManager default config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS0O9.png)

In my project(.net blazor), localized strings are used only in .cs and .razor files.
Here's what i've tried in config:

- Added a new line for .razor file extension.
- Tried multiple RegEx: "($Key)" ($Key) $Key

Did I miss some other configuration options? I also noticed how quick it determines that there are zero code references of a resource. Its almost like it doesn't even look through any of these .razor or .cs files.